# System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension cannot aplied property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Perhaps the problem exists in the binding process path. I do not know I am a stripling, I would be grateful for any suggestions :)
I have big problem when I add this code `ColorConverter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"` to my Calendar Control from WPControls.dll 
ColorConverter.cs is a class whose task is to color the selected days. 
When I exclude    `ColorConverter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"`
 Calendar is work very well... Restart VS2013 and rebuild not works

This is my MainPage

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Ap_1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"

    xmlns:wpControls="clr-namespace:WPControls;assembly=WPControls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ap_1" 
    Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded" >

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Here is my Calendar in MainPage

```
<!--Panorama item Calendar-->
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Kalendarz studenta">
   <!--Single line list with text wrapping-->
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel222" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <wpControls:Calendar 
          x:Name="Cal"
          ColorConverter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"  
         />                        
      <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=Cal,Path=SelectedDate}"/>
   </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Here is ColorConverter.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WPControls;


namespace Ap_1
{
    public class ColorConverter : IDateToBrushConverter
    {

        public Brush Convert(DateTime dateTime, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType)
        {
            if (brushType == BrushType.Background)
            {
                if (dateTime == new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 5))
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                }
                else
                {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (dateTime == new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 6))
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
                else
                {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is IDateToBrushConverter.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ap_1
{
    public interface IDateToBrushConverter
    {
        Brush Convert(DateTime dateTime, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType);
    }
}
```

Here is problem:

> Exception: An object of the type "Ap_1.ColorConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "WPControls.IDateToBrushConverter".
>
> Stack Trace:
>     at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.UpdatePropertyOrChildValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, Int32 childIndex, DocumentNodeChangeAction action, DocumentNode valueNode, ViewNode& childViewNode, IInstanceBuilder& valueBuilder, Boolean& isNewInstance)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.UpdateProperty(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.DependencyObjectInstanceBuilderBase`1.UpdateProperty(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.UpdateProperty(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateProperties(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, DocumentCompositeNode compositeNode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Initialize(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, Boolean isNewInstance)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.InitializeInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode, Boolean isNewInstance)

This is my screen
[image: screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you have 2 different `IDateToBrushConverter` interfaces. One in *WPControls* namespace, which is used by `wpControls:Calendar.ColorConverter` property and second one in *Ap_1* namespace which is implemented by `ColorConverter` class hence the error

> An object of the type "Ap_1.ColorConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "WPControls.IDateToBrushConverter

Instead of defining second interface in *Ap_1* namespace use one from *WPControls* namespace

```cs
namespace Ap_1
{
    public class ColorConverter : WPControls.IDateToBrushConverter
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Previously, my solution 'Solution Ap_1' consisted of two projects: WPControlsExample and WPControls.
WPControlsExample - where there was a MainPage, WPControls reference and Color Converter.cs
  WPControls - wszytskie class for my Calendar and generic.xaml (style my Calednar).
I combined the two projects into one and the problem appeared, I do not know how to solve.


`<ResourceDictionary 
   ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ap_1">
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="local:Calendar">    
</ResourceDictionary>`

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. At the moment class and property don't share same interface, hence the error. As for the XAML your namespace does not have to be called _local_ and you can have more then one for example add `xmlns:wpcontrols="clr-namespace:WpControls"` and then `<wpcontrols:Calendar .../>`

Comment: I changed `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPControls"` in MainPage and in ColorConverter namespace on `namespace WPControls` and all works fine. Thank you